# adding file source with IFileSourceFilter

Tags: c++, filter, directshow, atl

I am writing a Directshow application which connects a file source to a MPEG4s DMO.
The graph looks like:
**File Source -> DMO Wrapper Filter -> Video Renderer.**
Here are my questions:
1. How can I add a file source filter in the graph ? I got this piece of code which graphedit plus generated. Is this piece of code correct ? I see that it uses "CComPtr" which needs "atlbase.h". With VS2010 Express edition I don't have the atl headers.

```
LPCOLESTR srcFile1 = L"C:\\Users\shyam\\Downloads\\sample.avi";
CComPtr<IBaseFilter> pBaseFilter;
hr = pBaseFilter.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_AsyncReader);
CComQIPtr<IFileSourceFilter> pFileSourceFilter = pBaseFilter;
ATLASSERT(pFileSourceFilter);
pFileSourceFilter->Load(srcFile1, NULL);
hr = pGB->AddFilter(pBaseFilter, L"File Source (Async.)");
```

2. I manually downloaded "atlbase.h" from net and I am encountering several build errors. What can be done in this case.

Please help me in moving in the right direction !!

Thanks,
Shyam

Answer (score 0):

The code generated above is correct. For getting rid of your compilation error, download and install the latest windows sdk. It should have the correct atl headers.

Comment: hmmm i think you are correct....it comes with regular visual studio editions and not express.. the easiest way out is to perhaps download the trial version of visual studio and work out the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to write C++ code for Directshow without ATL, but I strongly wouldn't recommend it unless you like spagetti with leaks.  Here's what your code would look like

```
IBaseFilter* pBaseFilter;
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_AsyncReader, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter, (void**)&pBaseFilter);

IFileSourceFilter* pFileSourceFilter = NULL;
hr = pBaseFilter->QueryInterface(IID_IFileSourceFilter, (void**)&pFileSourceFilter);

ASSERT(pFileSourceFilter != NULL);

hr = pFileSourceFilter->Load(L"C:\\Users\shyam\\Downloads\\sample.avi", NULL);

if (pFileSourceFilter)
    pFileSourceFilter->Release();

hr = pFileSourceFilter->AddFilter(pBaseFilter, L"AsyncReader");
```

You also need to check hr for errors at every step.
The latest Windows SDK may not have all the Directshow interfaces, so I suggest  Microsoft Windows SDK Update for Windows Vista (for qedit.h).  But seriously please don't write Directshow or COM code without ATL, even DirectshowLib in c# would be easier for a simple app.